# Asp.Net Service method Is Not Executing or Calling Inner Method or Statement on BeforeUnload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have `beforeunload` event in js which will hit the .asmx service method as provided below.

**.js event**

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function () {            
        var d, str;
        str = '{Id:"' + $('#hdnId').val() + '"}';
        d = str;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
            url: "../POC.asmx/fUpdateTimeInterval",
            data: d,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () {
                //  BlockUI();
            },
            success: function (data, Type, xhr) {//On Successfull service call

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function () {

            },
            failure: function () {

            }
        });
    });
```

**.asmx (Web Service)**

```
[WebMethod(true)]
        public int fUpdateTimeInterval(String Id)
        { 
            return new MY_POC.DLL.Survey().fUpdateTimeInterval(Id);
        }
```

The above service will then call the below mentioned method defined in DLL class file.

```
public int fUpdateTimeInterval(Int32 Id)
        {

            List<SqlParameter> objParam = new List<SqlParameter>()
            {
                new SqlParameter{ParameterName ="@Id",Direction=ParameterDirection.Input,DbType=DbType.Int32,Value= Id},
            };

            MY_POC.DLL.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("MY_UpdateTimeInterval", System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, objParam.ToArray());

            return 0;
        }
```

Now problem is when the page gets `load` on browser for first time I am getting current auto ID of the inserted row. If I refreshes the browser, then `beforeunload` event gets fired and update the row of received ID only. But if I close the tab or browser then the compiler would hit the service method and stops after opening brace, it does not executing further & not even showing any error.

After execution stops, I am getting the following message at `Output` screen of vs, but not showing any error.
[image]

Comment: What makes you think "it stops after opening brace"? Have you tried logging at different points of execution to make sure this is really what's happening?

Comment: yes, I have debugged step by step also it does not showing any error. Just after reaching at opening brace, execution gets stopped.

Comment: Have you checked the Windows Event viewer? I am almost certain this must be logging to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like execution of the request is being aborted because the browser is closing the connection.

You should consider using the [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API). It's well supported by almost all browsers and it's made for this purpose. From Mozilla's documentation:

> The main use case for the Beacon API is to send analytics such as
> client-side events or session data to the server. Historically,
> websites have used XMLHttpRequest for this, but browsers do not
> guarantee to send these asynchronous requests in some circumstances
> (for example, if the page is about to be unloaded). To combat this,
> websites have resorted to various techniques, such as making the
> request synchronous, that have a bad effect on responsiveness. Because
> beacon requests are both asynchronous and guaranteed to be sent, they
> combine good performance characteristics and reliability.

You can also make your Ajax request **synchronous** to prevent the connection from closing but that will have an impact on your GUI as it will block until the request completes.